# Export graph in a .txt

Tags: python, pandas, export, txt

I created my graph using this line of code:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
plt.hist(Obs1, color="lightgrey", edgecolor="black", density=True)
```

Now I have to export the graph with the results in an .txt file, I exported the results using this line of code:

```
with open('process_results.txt', "w") as results:
results.write("PROCESS CAPABILITY ANALYSIS\n")

results.write("-----------------------------------\n")
results.write(f"Specifications\n")
results.write(f"\nTaget: {Target}\n")
results.write(f"LSL: {LSL}\n")
results.write(f"USL: {USL}\n")
```

How can I include the above graph as well?

Comment: How would you render a graph in a text file?

Comment: I would like to export it as an image

Comment: Why do you think this is possible in a *text* file?

Comment: Ok, I get the problem, can I do in a pdf file?

Comment: Yes. Take your pick of appropriate file format.

Comment: There is an example in the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/backend_pdf_api.html#matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf.PdfPages) for generating pdfs. You should also have a look at the `attach_note` method below the example. It allows you to export your results as well.

Answer (score 0):

**You can't export graph directly in txt file but you can export it as image or pdf**

## Here you can try this solution

```
...
...
...
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 10))
plt.hist(Obs1, color="lightgrey", edgecolor="black", density=True)

plt.savefig('graph.png')  # use this to export graph as png

template = """
    PROCESS CAPABILITY ANALYSIS
    ---------------------------
    Specifications
    Target: {target}
    LSL: {lsl}
    USL: {usl}
    """

with open('process_results.txt', "w") as results:
    results.write(template.format(target=Target, lsl=LSL, usl=USL))
```